# Using existing Java Frame Form In another Window

Tags: java, forms, swing, containers

I'm in the process of coding a little notepad-like application. I have a JFrame that I use to display statistics (word count, char count and all).

I'm wondering if it's possible for me to use that Frame in my main window as a Stats Panel that I could just show or hide instead of having a new window to pop out.

I'm a real Java noobie so perhaps I'm just no using the right tools. I've tried putting my Frame in a SplitPane, Panel and Internal Frame without any luck.

Any and every suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short cut is to get your JFrame's contentPane by calling `getContentPane()` on it, and then putting it where you want since it is a JPanel, but this is one reason why I think that folks should not code to the JFrame but rather to the JPanel. If instead your class was geared towards creating a JPanel from the very beginning, then you would have the flexibility of showing that panel in its own JFrame, in another JPanel as part of a more complex GUI, in a JDialog, a JApplet, or wherever you'd like.

So in sum, I suggest you re-write your GUI and gear it to make a JPanel. Also, if you're using NetBeans to create your GUI, you'll find that it may be less flexible compared to creating your GUI by hand with your own choice of layout managers since by doing it on your own, you can make your panel resize much more easily and cleanly.

Comment: *"Also, if you're using NetBeans to create your GUI, you'll find that it may be less flexible compared to creating your GUI by hand"*  I don't entirely agree with that.  Flexible, squeezy GUIs can be made in the Netbeans GUI builder using the standard J2SE layouts.  It is just a matter of knowing how to use it. +1 for the 1st para.

Comment: Agree, but too many take the easy way and default to the GroupLayout.